# Java DOM Node matching

Tags: java, string, dom, xpath

I am parsing an XML using DOM Parser in my Java program, which has an element node, say something like

```
 <elemname attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
```

I want to check if it matches with string (sort-of xpath)  representation of the element like

elemname[@attr1="value1"]

The string representation may not have all the attributes which are present in the actual node, however, it should still be a match.

Any idea how can this be achieved in an easier way ?

Comment: In modern browsers, you have `document.querySelectorAll('elemname[attr1=value]')`, where the string para,eter is a CSS selector expression (not a XPath one). If you need to support older browsers, you'll have to select by tag name and iterate/check all atributes' values yourself.

Comment: You can apply XPath with Java, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html for an introduction.